# What is the use case for type migration in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea, automated-refactoring

Okay so I have this variable declaration

```
 private List<String> params;
```

and I wanted to change the type of params to :

```
private Collection<String> params;
```

I choose `Refactor-->Type Migration (the combination of Ctrl+Shift+F6)` from the context menu but nothing happens.

My questions are :

1. What is the purpose of type migration then ?
2. How am I going to achieve what I need to achieve most efficiently ?

Comment: It work's like a charm for me. Make sure that the cursor is on `List<String>` and not anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way it works but the **text** cursor needs to be inside `List<String>` and NOT in the name of the reference `params` since you want to refactor the type and not the reference.

Comment: I am defnitely refactoring the type of params here and not  List<String>

Comment: @Geek You have to put the text cursor inside List<String> and not select the whole type or put it in the variable name. Also make sure you are using the latest version.